# Is there any opportunity to stop chown on first error?

Tags: bash, error-handling, chown

When I use recursive chown I'd like to stop it on first error.

```
$ chown -R /tmp/cache someuser
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/cache/1/thumbnail/100x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/h/d': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/cache/1/thumbnail/100x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/h': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/cache/1/thumbnail/100x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/cache/1/thumbnail/100x': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/cache/1/thumbnail': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/cache/1': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/cache': Operation not permitted
```

I.e. I should get only first error and status code "1" of `echo $?`.
Is it possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, this would probably be better asked at unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com

Comment: Did you forget a `-R`?

Comment: Succinctly, no; I don't think there's a (standard) way to have `chown -R` stop on the first error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only way to detect such an error would be to watch the standard error, but by the time you could detect and react to an error, `chown` will have continued on its way. If you need to take action after any error, you'll need to run `chown` separately on each file, taking action if there is an error.

```
# Assuming bash 4 for simplicity; handling the recursive directory walk
# without ** is left as an exercise for the reader.
shopt -s globstar
for f in /tmp/cache/**/*; do
    chown "$f" someuser || break
done
```

(It's entirely possible that someone *could* implement `chown` with an option to stop after the first error, but such an option doesn't exist in either the POSIX specification or in GNU `chown`.)